# Проверить упорядочен ли заданный массив по убыванию

Tags: c#, массивы

По возрастанию я проверил, а вот по убыванию не пойму как правильно сделать.

```
        int m = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int d = 0;
        bool up = false;
        bool dn = false;
        Console.Write("Введите колличество элементов в массиве ");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out m) || m <= 0)
            Console.Write("Необходимо ввести целое число!\nВведите число: ");
        int[] a = new int[m];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Введите элемент массива по индексом {i}");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out m) || m <= 0)
                Console.Write("Необходимо ввести целое число!\nВведите число: ");
            a[i] = m;
            if (g < m)
            {
                g = m;
                up = true;
            }
            else up = false;
        }

        //Array.Reverse(a);
        //for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        //{
        //}
        
        if (up)
            Console.WriteLine($"возростатет");
        //if (dn)
        //    Console.WriteLine($"УБВАЕТ");


    }
}
```

}

Comment: так же, как и повозрастанию, только с противоположным знаком при сравнении

Comment: Так не работает, при проверки на возрастание g < m и up == true. А при проверке на убывание условие не выполняется, так как g == 0.

Comment: Чтобы проверить массив на упорядоченность, нужно всего лишь сравнить все его соседние элементы, это пара строк кода. Что ваш код делает я не понял.

Comment: `for (int i=1; i<arr.len; i++) if (arr[i] <= arr[i-1]) return false; return true;` - проверка на возрастание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще сказать, что изначально последовательность возрастающая, и потом доказать обратное, т.к. для этого достаточно всего лишь найти 2 соседних элемента, которые `a[i - 1] >= a[i]`.

Аналогично с убывающей, сначала говорим, что последовательность убывает и в процессе проверки пытаемся доказать обратное, найдя два соседних элемента, которые `a[i - 1] <= a[i]`

Вот пример:

```
//Доказываем, что последовательность не возрастающая
if (i > 0 && a[i - 1] >= a[i])
    up = false;
//И так же не убывающая 
if (i > 0 && a[i - 1] <= a[i])
    dn = false;
```

Comment: `i > 0` нет смысла отсчитывать от 0

Comment: убывающая != невозрастающая

Comment: @tym32167 я в курсе, сначала ответ пишу, а потом правлю

Comment: @tym32167 насчет первого комментария, если проверки делать в 1 цикле с вводом, то это не обходимо. Ну или выносить введение первого элемента за цикл, что не очень красиво

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а то я совсем уже затупил.))